# Getting char values or text formatting from substrings in a Google sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hello ~ I am using Google sheets as a data store and have written a custom JSON exporter. 
I'd like users to be able to use sheets for text formatting and layout.
I know how to detect the formatting for an entire cell, but not the individual words inside of the string I have from getValue();

Is this at all possible?
Can I get the individual char values?

Comment: what do you mean individual  char values?

Comment: I mean if I can't get ranges of text formatting, can I get the raw char values of the string, so the unicode characters.  If I have these I can tell if a specific character is bold or not.